# Use domain with existing Wordpress install

Tags: domain

I have a working, self-hosted Wordpress install residing in my webspace at crypticname.online.de/Mysite/ and acquired a domain, let's say mysite.de. I would like mysite.de to request the home page of crypticname.online.de/Mysite/ and 
mysite.de/photos/ -> crypticname.online.de/Mysite/photos/ 
but without actually changing the url in the browser to the cryptic address.

The respective pages in the Wordpress codex only explain how to move a site from one location to another but I didn't find a solution to this particular problem. What kind of settings do I need to set in the Wordpress backend and at my domain name provider?

Comment: This isn't a specific wordpress question. It would be more on topic on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) (or another site?). To point you in de right direction: you'll have to set the DNS records of `mysite.de` to the old URL.

Comment: I thought the whole process would include changing settings in the Wordpress backend, so I posted it here.

Comment: Depending on the solution this **is** a WordPress question, because WordPress will redirect the address to the canonical URL in some setups.

Comment: @toscho Oh, sorry, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Lol i'll tell you what i would do: i'd use XCloner plugin (case sensitive search on install plugins menu), create a domain in my host like i would normally do and then use the "clone' function in XCloner to install the wordpress in the new dir, it works great.

first, register the new domain under your host. It will generate a folder for it, right?

1. Install 'XCloner' trought wordpress admin
2. acess XCloner under plugins menu
3. login admin/admin
4. generate a backup
5. if you'll overwrite a mySQL db, make sure you select "add Drop Sintax"
6. after generating the backup, click on CLONE blue button upper-right
7. put your ftp details.. attention for the folder, should be like htdocs/mysite , or the path you use by ftp to enter your new domains folder1
8. click clone (wait for upload, it has no progress bar, you can watch the progress trough your ftp client)
9. after sucessfully uploaded, you'll put you DB info.... then it will work under your new domain

Comment: really -2? what for? it should solve the guys problem ¬¬ i have nothing to do with this plugin development, i just use it (a lot)

Comment: There is no explanation on how this works, as well as it does not cover what Settings have to be set, as asked.

Comment: got it, sorry. But it would solve his problem anyways

Comment: i'll try to improve the awnser

Comment: Unfortunately my domain provider and my webspace provider are not the same - this means I do not have webspace at the company that provides my domain name.

Comment: can't you transfer the domain you already have to the webspace company you use?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this is to let your domain point to the WordPress directory, in your case: `/mysite` from your root web folder. This usually can be done either by your hoster or in your cPanel/administration tools.

You also have to change `WordPress Url` and `Site Url` in your WordPress Settings to your new Domain.

If you have no way of changing the directory your domain points to on your server, you can COPY (not move) the `index.php` from your WordPress folder to your root directory, as well as the `.htaccess`.

Inside the `index.php` in your root directory you have to change the include path of `wp-blog-header` from

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

to

```
require('./MySite/wp-blog-header.php');
```

And change the `WordPress Url` in your WordPress Settings to `http://www.mysite.de/MySite`, so WordPress knows that it's files are located in a Subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think the point where I'm stuck is "point to the WordPress directory". My domain name provider (United Domains) provides different ways, two of them (one of them is probably the right one) are "Header Redirect" and "URL Hiding". Do you have any advice on which one to take?

Comment: As your webspace provider and domain provider are not the same, I would suggest solution two. You can either set the ARECORD of your domain to the IP of your webspace provider, and set up the domain there, or you use the URL Hiding. But this discussion is OffTopic here - I'd ask at StackExchange for the Setup of your Domains, and use this answer to configure your WordPress Setup.

Comment: To get ontopic again: I have isolated the problem to the Wordpress side of the story. When I use URL Hiding to point to the correct directory on the server and use www.mysite.de as both `WordPress URL` and `Site URL`, the home page of the blog is loaded when I enter www.mysite.de, but it says "No posts found" and I can't access any other pages of the blog, e.g. www.mysite.de/wp-config.php. Looks pretty bad until there but I noticed that some records from the DB are loaded through a custom function I wrote to retrieve gig dates from the plugin "Tribe Event Calendar".